# How to turn Razor Model into JS object in a Razor For Loop?

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, asp.net-mvc-4, razor

I have a Razor for loop:

```
@foreach (var user in Model.Users)
        {
        <p class="active-text">Active: @user.LastActive</p>
        }
```

I've just installed moment.js to format this DateTime() date using js.

How can I pass the Razor model into a javascript function?  I do have a JS viewmodel for this page, I'm just trying to avoid serializing the entire Model just because I need to apply some JS to a single field.  How my viewModel stands right now:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(ko.applyBindings(new SubjectVm()));
</script>
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would wrap the date text in another span for later processing:

```
<p class="active-text">Active: <span class="active-text-date">@user.LastActive</span></p>
```

Then loop through and apply the formatting, inside document.load:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function() {
        $(".active-text-date").each(function() {
            var date = $(this).text();
            var formatted = moment(date).calendar();
            $(this).text(formatted);
        });
    });
</script>
```